# sticky div in fluid container: flickering and resize to full browser window problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make a sticky div that stays at the top, when one scrolls past it. But I have two problems:

1. When the scroll area is really small (almost no scrolling) than it flickers and scrolling is impossible.
2. It is a responsive and fluid desgin using bootstrap. When I scroll down it stretches to the browser window size on the right side. How can I restrain the sticky div to the size of the container?

Here is the CSS for the sticky div:

```
.wrapper{
margin: 0 auto 0; 
top: 0;  
width:100%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
background-color:#fff;
border-top: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

And the sticky-class:

```
.sticky {  
position: fixed;  
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto 0;
top: 0;  
z-index: 100;  
border-top: 0;  
}
```

And the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('.wrapper').offset().top;  

    var stickyNav = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

    if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
        $('.wrapper').addClass('sticky');  
    } else {  
        $('.wrapper').removeClass('sticky');   
    }  
    };  

    stickyNav();  

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();  
    });  
    });
```

You can test the whole version here: http://labs.tageswoche.ch/budget/budget.html.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pc4sucms/

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle

Comment: Could the `removeClass` call be causing a bunch of redrawing?  I wonder if you only removed the class if it was there.  like `if ($('.wrapper').hasClass('sticky')) { $('wrapper').removeClass('sticky'); }` .  I was not able to see the flickering in the fiddle, though I did see it on your shared link.

Comment: i dont know how to apply your code, if i replace the if-statement i have with your code, the div doesn't stick. If i make the fiddle smaller, then i can see the flickering. it flickers if the scroll area is really small.

Comment: Could this be a !DOCTYPE issue? http://labs.tageswoche.ch/budget/budget.html doesn't have a !DOCTYPE.